# How to call the Redux actions from the Custom Drawer

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

I'm writing the code for the Dynamically App theme changing. The app theme is changing when I'm calling the actions from the `HomeScreen class`. but I want to change the App theme and call the actions from the drawer's button.

I want to call the `this.props.switchTheme()` from the Drawer Button. using this I can change the App theme from the Drawer Button.

please help me to do this.

`it's my action.js`

```
 export const switchTheme = (BaseTheme) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type      : 'SWITCH_THEME',
        baseTheme : BaseTheme
    });
  };
};
```

`it's my App.js`

```
export default class App extends Component {
 render() {
     return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Container />
        </Provider>
    );
 }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 Home : { screen: HomeScreen },
 pro  : {
    screen : Profile
 },

});

const customDrawerComponent = (props) => {
return (
    <View>
        <View
            style={{
                height          : 60,
                backgroundColor : '#437564',
                alignItems      : 'center',
                justifyContent  : 'center',
                paddingVertical : 5
            }}
        />
        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
 );
};
 const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    Home : {
        screen : AppStackNavigator
    }
},
{
    drawerPosition   : 'left',
    contentComponent : customDrawerComponent,
    contentOptions   : {
        activeTintColor   : '#4c8572',
        inactiveTintColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    }
  }
 );

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    theme : state.themeReducer.theme
  };
 }

const Container = createAppContainer(DrawerNav);
```

`it's is my HomeScreen`

```
   class HomeScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerStyle      : {
            backgroundColor : '#4c8572'
        },
        headerLeft       : (
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        ),
        headerTitleStyle : {
            flex           : 1,
            color          : '#fff',
            alignItems     : 'center',
            justifyContent : 'center',
            fontWeight     : 'bold'
        }
    };
};

render() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={this.props.theme}>
            <Container>
                <TextContainer>
                    <Title>Change my theme</Title>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('pro')}
                    >
                        <Title>go to Profile</Title>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </TextContainer>
                {this.props.theme.mode === 'light' ? (
                    <Button onPress={() => this.props.switchTheme(darkTheme)}>
                        <ButtonText>Change to dark theme</ButtonText>
                    </Button>
                ) : (
                    <Button onPress={() => this.props.switchTheme(lightTheme)}>
                        <ButtonText>Change to light theme</ButtonText>
                    </Button>
                )}
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
     );
   }
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    theme : state.themeReducer.theme
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { switchTheme })(HomeScreen);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem before. You can do what you did for the HomeScreeen to the drawer, which is mapDispatchToProps.

simply replace customDrawerComponent component with the following code

```
const _customDrawerComponent = (props) => {
return (
    <View>
        <View
            style={{
                height          : 60,
                backgroundColor : '#437564',
                alignItems      : 'center',
                justifyContent  : 'center',
                paddingVertical : 5
            }}
        />
        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
 );
};

const customDrawerComponent = connect(null, { switchTheme }(_customDrawerComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... But where i write this code... Can you tell me in details.